# Can I mix static and shared-object libraries when linking?

Tags: c, gcc, static, linker

I have a C project that produces ten executables, all of which I would like to be linked in statically. The problem I am facing is that one of these executables uses a 3rd-party library of which only the shared-object version is available.

If I pass the `-static` flag to gcc, ld will error saying it can't find the library in question (I presume it's looking for the .a version) and the executable will not be built.  Ideally, I would like to be able to tell 'ld' to statically link as much as it can and fail over to the shared object library if a static library cannot be found.

In the interium I tried something like `gcc -static -lib1 -lib2 -shared -lib3rdparty foo.c -o foo.exe` in hopes that 'ld' would statically link in lib1 and lib2 but only have a run-time dependence on lib3rdparty. Unfortunatly, this did not work as I intended; instead the `-shared` flag overwrote the `-static` flag and everything was compiled as shared-objects.

Is statically linking an all-or-nothing deal, or is there some way I can mix and match?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Looking at  [this thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2001-07/msg01444.html) you can see that it can be done. The guys at GNU suggest

```
gcc foo.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lbar -lbaz -lqux -Wl,-Bdynamic -lcorge -o foo.exe
```

Comment: Is there a missing "-l" prefix on the list of libs following "-Wl,-Bstatic <list of libs>; should it be: -Wl,-Bstatic -llib2 -llib2 -llib3 ???

Comment: @HestonT.Holtmann It's implied, but I'll fix it up so it's clearer.

Comment: @Anthony How to do the same with LDFLAGS ?