# How do you link a static library to a shared library

Tags: c++, linker, ld

I'm trying to link a static library to a shared library via a command like

```
g++ -shared obj.o archive.a -o libLib.so
```

But at run time I keep getting unresolved system that should be link at compile time from archive.a.  I've tried

```
 g++ -shared obj.o -Wl,-Bstatic archive.a -Wl,-Bdynamic -o libLib.so
```

and

```
g++ -shared obj.o -Wl,-whole-archive archive.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive -o libLib.so
```

with no success.  I feel like I'm missing something basic here...

Comment: Your second attempt looks like a mangled version of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954387/can-i-mix-static-and-shared-object-libraries-when-linking) which is actually for producing an executable from the inputs of both static and shared objects.  However you are trying to output a shared object so that is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You practically cannot (i.e. should *never*) do that. [Shared libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) should be [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), but static libraries are not.

<sup>If you want to link `libaa` into `libfoo.so` build or get a *shared* (PIC) library `libaa.so`, not a static (non-PIC) library `libaa.a`</sup>

So a file `foo1.cc` going into a shared library `libfoo.so` should be compiled as

```
g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -O foo1.cc -o foo1.pic.o
```

and the library will be linked as

```
g++ -shared foo1.pic.o foo2.pic.o -o libfoo.so
```

<sup>You could link another shared library `libsmiling.so` into `libfoo.so` e.g. by appending `-lsmiling` to the above command. But you can't link libraries into static libraries, just copy their members.</sup>

But a file going into a *static* library `libfoo.a` is just compiled as

```
g++ -Wall -O foo1.cc -o foo1.o
```

so when you extract that `foo1.o` member from `libfoo.a` it is *not* PIC (and that is very inefficient)

In principle you could put a non-PIC object code in a shared library. In practice, you should never do that, because the amount of [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) is so large that it defeats the purpose of *shared* libraries. If you did that, text memory won't be *sharable* and the dynamic linker would have a *lot* of relocation work.

Code inside `.so` shared objects should be PIC to permit `ld.so` to `mmap` it at different address segments in different processes.

<sup>So you could find a sequence of commands to link a static library into a shared one, e.g. extract using `ar x` all the members of the `libbar.a`  then link all these extracted `bar*.o` with `foo*.pic.o` but that would be a mistake. Don't link static non-PIC libraries or object files to PIC shared libraries.</sup>

For details (with a focus on Linux) read [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) wikipage, [Levine's book: *Linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/), [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

<sup>PS. Some very few static libraries contain PIC code because they could be used to make shared libraries. For example my Debian provides the `libc6-pic` package giving notably the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_pic.a` static PIC library -usable to build some variant of `libc.so` -e.g. if I wanted to put my own `malloc` in `libc.so`! - without recompiling every *glibc* source file.</sup>

Comment: Wow !This is probably the most complete answer I've seen on the subject -- thx!  Althought, when I compile the object used for the archive as PIC code, it'll link -- but it's not often that archives are compiled with -fPIC though