# How to deploy a Linux application with extra libraries

Tags: linux, deployment

So I am in the following situation:

We are writing an application which needs to be deployed onto the customer machines which are running either some older version of Ubuntu (16.04 or some older) or Debian 9. Till today our application was packaged as a standard `.deb` package and it had system dependencies in a way that a sane `apt install` could handle installing it together with all its dependencies (such as `Qt`, `sqlite`, `gdal`, `proj`, etc...).

Due to some requirements however recently we have developed a few features which require that some libraries, specifically `gdal` and `proj` are using the latest version of aforementioned libraries, which are not to be found on these older systems and we can't got to each of our customer and compile these libraries on their machines.

So, obviously the question comes:

What are the best recommendations to deploy our application in the most painless way with the new libraries onto the old systems?

I have looked into AppImage but I just can't get my head around it (and did not find a good tutorial on how to deploy a Qt application with it), and flatpak and snap are not good, since we don't want to depend on any other repositories.

Comment: maybe mix static and dynamic linking as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954387/can-i-mix-static-and-shared-object-libraries-when-linking

Comment: In general I would say go with AppImage. Can you give more details about the nature of the app? At least programming language.