# How to mix linking both static and shared libraries with CMake

Tags: dynamic, cmake, static-libraries

I have a shared library libtest.so built on Linux. It links to several shared libraries. Now I have some third party static libraries to link to libtest.so. I am aware this is possible by calling gcc directly:

[Can I mix static and shared-object libraries when linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954387/can-i-mix-static-and-shared-object-libraries-when-linking)

My question is how to do the same thing with CMake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem. With your static library, you can do this:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target_or_executable /home/me/somedir/mymagiclib.a)
```

Or

```
target_link_libraries(my_target_or_executable -L/home/me/somedir/)
target_link_libraries(my_target_or_executable mymagiclib.a)
```

I even linked to shared libraries yesterday this way. Because I had a conflict in gcc's address sanitizer library coming from multiple sources.

Notice however the difference with linking to a library, the normal way. For your `libtest.a`, you do this:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target_or_executable -ltest)
```

Notice that you dropped the `lib` prefix here. But don't do this when you want to specify the library manually.