# Compiling CUDA code while linking a static library

Tags: c, compilation, cuda, g++, nvcc

I have C code `main_code.c` and `helper_code.c`. The former depends on some CUDA code `cuda_code.cu` and the latter on an external library `mylib`. For my external library `mylib` to work, I need to link it to my code with the `-static` flag:

```
g++ main_code.c helper_code.c -o main_code -static -L/usr/local/mylib/lib -lmylib -lmylib2
```

But `main_code.c` also depends on CUDA code- `cuda_code.cu`. I can link it with:

```
nvcc cuda_code.cu -c
g++ main_code.c -o main_code cuda_code.o -L/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64 -lcudart -lpthread
```

I want to compile my code together with the CUDA code and the external library `mylib`. However, linking `mylib` works only with the `-static` flag. A naive attempt would be the following but it does not work:

```
nvcc cuda_code.cu -c
g++ main_code.c helper_code.c -o main_code cuda_code.o -static -L/usr/local/mylib/lib -lmylib -lmylib2 -L/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64 -lcudart -lpthread
```

This gives the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
```

which I'm assuming is because you cannot use the static flag while linking with CUDA (because it goes away when I remove the `-static` flag (in addition to also removing the `mylib` library linking)).

I then tried compiling `helper_code.c` separately and then linking it to `main_code.c` since it's just `helper_code.c` that needs `mylib`:

```
helper.o:
    g++ helper_code.c -c -static -L/usr/local/mylib/lib -lmylib -lmylib2

cuda-code.o:
    nvcc cuda_code.cu -c

main-code: helper.o cuda-code.o
    g++ main_code.c -o main_code helper_code.o cuda_code.o -L/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64 -lcudart -lpthread
```

But this also does not work. I get an `undefined reference` error that's referring to a function defined in `mylib`, meaning the linking to `mylib` isn't working. I can resolve that error by including the `mylib` library and using the `-static` flag but that then breaks the CUDA linking.

I can separately get the CUDA linking (to `cuda_code.cu`) to work or `mylib` linking to work but not both at the same time.

So is there a workaround to link `mylib` (which needs `-static`) while at the same time also linking my CUDA code (which does not allow `-static`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2954387/681865 , and CUDA fully supports static linking on Linux. You just need to use the static version of the runtime library

Comment: try `-lcudart_static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer linked in talonmies's comment, the following did the trick:

```
g++ main_code.c -o main_code helper_code.o cuda_code.o -L/usr/local/mylib/lib -L/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64 -Wl,-Bstatic -lmylib -lmylib2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lcudart
```